# How to make new person in class player?

Tags: python, class

i have a programm here that i made and i trying to add a new player. Every time i try it comes up with an error could someone please help me.
Thanks in advance,
-Josh

```
          def main():
            class Player:
                def __init__(self, name, tank_name):
                    self.name = name
                    self.tank_name = tank_name
            def new_player():
                p1 = Player()
                p1.name = input('What is your name >>> ')
                p1.tank_name = input('What is your tanks name >>> ')
            new_player()
        
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            main()
```

Comment: Don't put class definitions inside the `main()` function.

Comment: Hey Barmar thx for the quick response but idk how to do that im not great a python. could you add an example

Answer (score 0):

`name` and `tank_name` are required parameters for the `__init__` method. You need to ask for them before creating the `Player`, not assign them after.

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, tank_name):
        self.name = name
        self.tank_name = tank_name

def new_player():
    name = input('What is your name >>> ')
    tank_name = input('What is your tanks name >>> ')
    p1 = Player(name, tank_name)

new_player()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set `name` and `tank_name` parameters to `None` for `__init__` method

```
    def main(): 
        class Player:
                    def __init__(self, name=None, tank_name=None):
                        self.name = name
                        self.tank_name = tank_name
                def new_player():
                    p1 = Player()
                    p1.name = input('What is your name >>> ')
                    p1.tank_name = input('What is your tanks name >>> ')
                new_player()
            
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```